# Circle with dotted or dashed border

Tags: html, css

With this CSS styles I expect a circle with dotted border:

```
div{
    border: 1px dotted #000;
    padding: 50px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But Firefox is rendering solid borders ([fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/7jV8y/)). Any solution?

**UPDATE**
THIS IS NOT AN ISSUE ANY MORE.
RESOLVED in Firefox 50

Comment: i have to chuckle that none of the asker, the above comment author, or the other answer author thought to try this in more than their pet browser  :)

Comment: You might need to increase the width of that border to, say, 3px

Comment: @Eevee - at least my "pet browser" can draw borders correctly. In all seriousness, I can reproduce with FF 24, even with a different border width.

Comment: well MY browser was an honor student!

Comment: Well, it works on Chrome. You might need to wait until they fix that bug, or you can draw it with `<canvas>`, as Eevee suggested :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're using Firefox, this is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721).  Your options are:

- If this is just for the sake of a circle, draw it with `<canvas>`, e.g. as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6295564/17875)
- Use SVG (possibly inline), which supports various ways to [stroke paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes)
- Just make a PNG
- Fix the bug, which Mozilla will surely appreciate  ;)

Comment: OMG, I prefer to give up and use a trapezoid instead of fixing this bug. Of-course not just for fixing the bug, but forcing users to update their browsers ;)

Comment: ah, thinking of the users!  how very selfless of you  ;)