# Dashed border not showing in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have a radius div with 5px dashed border, but border not show properly in `Firefox`.
It show well in IE and chrome.

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/64j3w00k/)</kbd>

```
 div{
        height:100px;
        width: 100px;
        background-color: #ccc;
        border-radius: 50%;
        border:5px dashed #333;
    }
```

Comment: But  I am using FF 32.0.3 and its not working.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see `dashed`... It seems that it doesn't work in FF.

Comment: I don't how its work for you, i am also check with all resolution on my machine.

Comment: It's a bug. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725351/css-border-radius-for-dotted-border). And [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756049/why-does-border-5px-dashed-not-come-out-as-dashed-in-firefox)

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of the question @Michel refers to, although it is titled just “CSS border radius for dotted border”—but the underlying bug is the same.

Comment: OK, this is clearly a dup of the other old question.

Comment: Sure its duplicate, but it deserve proper answer acceptable ans.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your border is working on firefox see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/64j3w00k/5/) you can check it with removing radius. FireFox having bug when you tried circle with dashed border.

This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721).  Your options are:

- If this is just for the sake of a circle, draw it with `<canvas>`, e.g. as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6295564/17875)
- Use SVG (possibly inline), which supports various ways to [stroke paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes)
- Just make a Image PNG

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug, Here are all the other outstanding border-radius defects in Firefox.
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=431176

old thread

[Why does border: 5px dashed not come out as dashed in Firefox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756049/why-does-border-5px-dashed-not-come-out-as-dashed-in-firefox)

you can achieve it using image

http://www.guyroutledge.co.uk/blog/better-dotted-borders-with-border-image/

Comment: This is an uncredited copy from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756049/why-does-border-5px-dashed-not-come-out-as-dashed-in-firefox

Comment: yes it is, i am providing the information here how to achieve it along with second link.