# how can i increase border width on hover without dislodging the div position in css?

Tags: css

i'm trying to have it so that hovering on a circular div causes a thick dotted border to radiate outwards while keeping the inner area in the same place. (the idea is to give the impression of a blooming flower.) so far everything i've tried has resulted in the center moving to accomodate the increase in border width. is there a way to accomplish what i want with pure css?

this is what i'm using:

```
#f {
    left:10px;
    top:10px;
    position:fixed;
    border:10px dotted #0db;
    border-radius:50%;
    width:43px;
    height:43px;
    -webkit-transition: border .4s ease-in;
    -moz-transition: border .4s ease-in;
    -o-transition: border .4s ease-in;
}

#f:hover {
    border:40px dotted #fb0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest would be to set `box-sizing: border-box;` and increase the elements size with the border's now set width.

Since `box-sizing: border-box;` make border width within the size of the element, it will keep its size on a border resize.

*Side notes:*

Don't forget to add the non-prefixed `transition: border .4s ease-in;` to your rule.

Be also aware of that dotted borders in Firefox and Edge/IE11 doesn't look the same as in Chrome.

FF doesn't show it at all actually, [Dashed border not showing in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26354560/dashed-border-not-showing-in-firefox)

```css
#f {
  left:10px;
  top:10px;
  position:fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border:10px dotted #0db;
  border-radius:50%;
  width:53px;
  height:53px;
  -webkit-transition: border .4s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: border .4s ease-in;
  -o-transition: border .4s ease-in;
  transition: border .4s ease-in;
}

#f:hover {
  border: 20px dotted #fb0;
}
```

```html
<div id="f"></div>
```

Answer (score 7):

use `outline`, insted of broder.

```css
#f {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: Grey;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 2px solid silver;
  transition: .1s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#f:hover {
  outline: 5px solid #fb0;
  transition: .1s linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="f">Button</div>
```

New Edit 2022: `border-radius` will work with `outline` in 2022

> Old Edit: Ok it seems my mistake, `border-radius` won't work
> `outline`. `outline` is fine for square boxes.
>
> There is a `-moz-outline-radius` but only for mozilla firefox.
> `box-shadow` is another way but it is tricky to use it for thick
> borders.
>
> In this case instead of `outline` use LGSon's `box-sizing:border-box`
> solution.

Comment: This won't work as `outline` doesn't follow the `border` when having `border-radius`.

Comment: @LGSon thaks, i completely forgot about it :S i have updated the answer pointing to your solution.

Answer (score 3):

### Answer from 2022:

@AvikB 's answer is correct.

Outline is worked with border-radius now in 2022.

Here is the gist:

```css
#f {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

#f:hover {
  outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="f">button</div>
```

As you can see, [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline) is much better than border in case it doesn't change the box size.