# Browser-wide dashed circle

Tags: css

I wanted to create a dashed border for my circle, but I can't seem to find any good solution. I'm trying this one:

```css
.test{
    width: 200px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 9px dashed #104F75;
    border-radius: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

And it seems to be working fine on **Chrome** and **Edge**, but when I open it in **Firefox**, the circle isn't dashed at all. Moreover, border looks different when I look at it using Chrome and Edge.

**I'm looking for browser-wide working solution for this kind of CSS effect,** not explenation that this is a Firefox bug.

Comment: @DaniP I edited the question, and could you please unmark this as duplicate? I'm not asking what is it, becuase I do realise it's a Firefox bug -   I'm looking for a **solution**.

Comment: What about the options here http://stackoverflow.com/a/26354776/2887133

Comment: it is a firefox bug, an svg could help http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/wBPLvL stroke-x values are to be tuned to match the size of your boxe :)